# LoadError (no such file to load -- action_controller/routing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, jruby

Suddenly I am getting `no such file to load -- action_controller/routing`

my **other methods in different controllers are working fine**, **only this one in create method** at

```
respond_to do |format|
```

Here is the log

```
LoadError (no such file to load -- action_controller/routing):
  lib/routing_extensions.rb:164:in `(root)'
.
.
.
 Rendered /home/appandya/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2@rails-3.2.11/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered /home/appandya/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2@rails-3.2.11/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered /home/appandya/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2@rails-3.2.11/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (18.0ms)
```

any help or direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `lib/routing_extensions.rb`, we have one plugin, need to be install as per rails 3.2.x way. This is working fine now